# Find the attribute value and replacing with new value of attribute in XML file

Tags: xml, powershell, jmx

Using Powershell, I want to make changes in XML file and the files that need change `0` to `${ThinkTime}` for the name `RandomTimer.range` in multiple places.

I want to check if `0` is present before replace.

XML message:

```xml
<UniformRandomTimer guiclass="UniformRandomTimerGui" testclass="UniformRandomTimer" testname="Think Time" enabled="true">
    <stringProp name="ConstantTimer.delay">${ThinkTime}</stringProp>
    <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">0</stringProp>
</UniformRandomTimer>
```

Below Powershell script is not working as expected:

```sh
Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users**\Desktop\Projects**\D****\scripts*.jmx | ForEach-Object { 
    $xmlDocument = [xml]($_ |Get-Content) 
    $tmConfig = $xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//UniformRandomTimer/stringProp[2]") 
    # attribute exists, let's update it! 
    if($tmConfig.GetAttribute('#text') -eq "0") { 
        $tmConfig.SetAttribute("#text", "${ThinkTime}") 
    } 
    $xmlDocument.Save($_.FullName) 
}
```

Comment: below Powershell script is not working as expected          
        **Get-ChildItem -Path C:\Users\***\Desktop\Projects\***\D****\scripts\***.jmx 
        |ForEach-Object 
        {
          $xmlDocument = [xml]($_ |Get-Content)
      $tmConfig = $xmlDocument.SelectSingleNode("//UniformRandomTimer/stringProp[2]")
       # attribute exists, let's update it!
          if($tmConfig.GetAttribute('#text') -eq "0")
        {
          $tmConfig.SetAttribute("#text", "${ThinkTime}")
        }
        $xmlDocument.Save($_.FullName)
        }**

Comment: Please add additional information to your question - not as comments. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've helped you with the formatting, but next time please try to format code samples "as code", see the [help section](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#syntax-highlighting). Also if you have additional information you can edit your question at any time by pressing the "Edit" link below it. Formatting in comments is very limited and it makes it easier for people willing to help, if everything is contained in the question.

Answer (score 1):

Your question isn't clear, but try making these changes and see if it works on your actual xml:

```
$tmConfig = $xml.SelectSingleNode('//UniformRandomTimer//stringProp[.="0"]')
$tmConfig.innerText = "something or other"
```

Comment: the attribute entirely removed After run the above.  :    
              
                  <stringProp name="RandomTimer.range">

Comment: @Raja What do you mean by "entirely removed"? Nothing in the code removes anything.

Comment: sorry. its not removing the attribute. and its changing the other element properties "<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration"></stringProp>" to "<stringProp name="ThreadGroup.duration">"

Comment: its removing "</stringProp>"  in all the elements node

Comment: @Raja The answer works for the sample xml in your question. The only thing I can think of is that your actual xml is very different from the sample.